# Get input after a mouse click SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I am making a form using SFML and I'm stuck in a place where after I click on a rectangle and THEN I get input. For testing purpose, I am using cout to print what I enter. Here's the code snippet.
event is an object of sf::Event, rect1 is the rectangle. in the if statement, i have specified the area where I click.
Now I want to print out what I type after I click on the rectangle. Please Help on this because I haven't cracked it for over 6 hrs.

...

```
switch (event.type){

   case Event::Closed:
      window.close();
            break;
        case Event::MouseMoved:
            //cout << event.mouseMove.x << ", " << event.mouseMove.y << endl;
            break;
        case Event::MouseButtonReleased:
            if (event.key.code==Mouse::Left
                && Mouse::getPosition(window).x >= rect1.getPosition().x
                && Mouse::getPosition(window).x <= rect1.getPosition().x + rect1.getSize().x
                && Mouse::getPosition(window).y >= rect1.getPosition().y
                && Mouse::getPosition(window).y <= rect1.getPosition().y + rect1.getSize().y) 
            {


                  //what I want to do is here I guess. 


            }
            break;


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're making a text box.

When the box is pressed you should toggle a boolean which shows whether the box is selected or not. Then, in another event, you should check if any text has been entered ([TextEntered](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/window-events.php#the-textentered-event) event). If they have, you should check if the text box is selected, and if it is, insert the characters.

Here is an example:

```
switch (event.type){

    case Event::Closed:
        window.close();
        break;
    case Event::MouseMoved:
        //cout << event.mouseMove.x << ", " << event.mouseMove.y << endl;
        break;
    case Event::MouseButtonReleased:
        if (event.key.code==Mouse::Left
            && Mouse::getPosition(window).x >= rect1.getPosition().x
            && Mouse::getPosition(window).x <= rect1.getPosition().x + rect1.getSize().x
            && Mouse::getPosition(window).y >= rect1.getPosition().y
            && Mouse::getPosition(window).y <= rect1.getPosition().y + rect1.getSize().y) 
        {
              // The box has been selected
              // Toggle the boolean
              isSelected = !isSelected;
        }
        break;
    case Event::TextEntered:
        if ( isSelected )
        {
            if ( event.Text.Unicode < 0x80 ) // it's printable
            {
                // Here is the character that was typed
                char keyString = (char) event.Text.Unicode;
                // Here you should add the character to perhaps a string containing the total text in the text box
            }
        }
}
```

This should let you capture the characters that are typed when the text box is selected.